# Set.add() in android SharedPreferences is not working as expected

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a string from SharedPreferences preference and put it back in another SharedPreferences preference.

getString() from the first preference "test1" and add it to the second preference using putStringSet().

sample code:

```
void test()
{
    Log.v("Main", "********");

    final SharedPreferences test1 = context.getSharedPreferences("test1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = test1.edit();
    editor1.clear();
    editor1.putString("sample1", "This is a test");
    editor1.apply();

    final SharedPreferences test2 = context.getSharedPreferences("test2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(test2.getStringSet("sample2", new HashSet<String>()));

    Log.v("Main", "set.size: " + set.size());

    Log.v("Main", test1.getString("sample1", null));
    set.add(new String(test1.getString("sample1", null)));

    Log.v("Main", "set.size: " + set.size());

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = test2.edit();
    editor2.clear();
    editor2.putStringSet("sample2", set);
    editor2.apply();
}
```

running the code 3 times results in:

```
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 0
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
```

the expected result is to have the second preference increased with each call since we are adding to the Set e.g.

```
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 0
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 2
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 2
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 3
```

i have already copied the Set that is coming from the second preference via getStringSet to avoid pointing to the same object.

The problem is with Set.add(getString()). if i use a normal string e.g. Set.add("text"), it will work. i tried to create another copy of the string e.g. set.add(new String(getString .... but this is also not working.

I have tried as well cleaning the editor or using commit() instead of apply() without luck.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: the reason is in the API document for getStringSet : "Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all."

Comment: check my answer. it worked for me! Test it..

Comment: do you know what a set does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie, I got what exactly is happening! **Set basically won't allow redundancy!** Kindly read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html#add(E)). It says

> Adds the specified object to this set. The set is not modified if it already contains the object.

So if you try to add the same object which is already exist then it won't be modified.

You need to add the new object which is not exist in set already! So I tried this code and it worked for me!

```
void test(int count) //count is nothing but number of iteration of loop
{
    Log.v("Main", "********");

    final SharedPreferences test1 = getSharedPreferences("test1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = test1.edit();
    editor1.clear();
    editor1.putString("sample1", "This is a test");
    editor1.apply();

    final SharedPreferences test2 = getSharedPreferences("test2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Set<String> set = test2.getStringSet("sample2", new HashSet<String>()); // Edited this line (Removed new HashSet<>) If you do then it creates new object each time. 

    Log.v("Main", "set.size: " + set.size());

    Log.v("Main", test1.getString("sample1", null));

    set.add(test1.getString("sample1" + " " + count, null) + " --- " + count); // along with the text I'm adding count so the object (string) are not same

    Log.v("Main", "set.size: " + set.size());

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = test2.edit();
    editor2.clear();
    editor2.putStringSet("sample2", set);
    editor2.apply();
}
```

And output is :

```
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 0
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 1
This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 2
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 2
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 3
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 3
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 4
V/Main﹕ ********
V/Main﹕ set.size: 4
V/Main﹕ This is a test
V/Main﹕ set.size: 5
```

And replace the line

`final HashSet set = new HashSet<>(test2.getStringSet("sample2", new HashSet<String>()));`

with

`final HashSet set = test2.getStringSet("sample2", new HashSet<String>());`